# How to achieve two echo statement output to same line in bash

Tags: linux

Example:
I have below test script

```
#!/bin/bash

output1=$(cat ~/Desktop/scripts/test)
output2=$(cat ~/Desktop/scripts/test2 |sed -e 's/^/\t/g')
echo -e "$output1 $output2"
```

When I execute above script I am getting below output

```
1234
5678
9123    ndfkjdskjgbsd
        sdnbfksdjgkjdsb
        sdnbvksd
        dbvksdbgf
```

But I am looking output like below, how can I achieve?

```
1234      ndfkjdskjgbsd
5678      sdnbfksdjgkjdsb
9123      sdnbvksd
          dbvksdbgf
```

Comment: As a rule, by the way, don't use `echo -e` without an extremely good reason to do so; it's not allowed by the POSIX standard for `echo` to do anything other than printing `-e` on output, so when you rely on it having a contrary behavior you're writing code that works only with shells that violate the standard (a set which, unfortunately, includes `bash` except when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are set). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Answer (score 2):

Use `paste`:

```
paste ~/Desktop/scripts/test ~/Desktop/scripts/test2
```

---

However, if you *really* want to do this in native shell as an exercise:

```
while IFS= read -r line1 <&3; IFS= read -r line2 <&4; [[ $line1 || $line2 ]]; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$line1" "$line2"
done 3<~/Desktop/script/test 4<~/Desktop/script/test2
```

This works by opening the first file on FD 3, the second file on FD 4, and working through both files line-by-line until there's no new content available from either.

Comment: paste is giving good result, while condition giving below output

1234 
5678 
9123 
 ndfkjdskjgbsd
 sdnbfksdjgkjdsb
 sdnbvksd
 dbvksdbgf